# What is the full list of emoticons on Facebook Chat?

Tags: facebook

I know of a few simple emoticons that translate to images like

`:)` turns into a smile;
`:putnam:` turns into a Facebook engineer named Putnam.

But what is the extent of emoticons available in chat? Is there somewhere where I can find the entire list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The list is = number of facebook users + ~10 normal emoticons(`:)`, `:P` etc).

No, not kidding, you can take any user's profile picture and turn it into an emoticon. Take anyone's profile find his profile ID and post it to chat like `[[PROFILE_ID]]`, and his/her profile image will turn into an emoticon. E.g. -

[image]

Try it. :)

**Update:** Finding the user ID is a bit tricky.

For the users who didn't setup a username, their profile page looks like this - `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002872529`, and you know that's the user ID.

For those who have setup an user ID - go to their profile page, view the source of that page with your browser(For chrome, you press Ctrl + U), search for this exact text - `profile_owner` and you'll see something like `&quot;profile_owner&quot;:&quot;100002872529&quot;`. There you have the ID.

This is the fastest way for me, if anyone has even faster way, please post. :P

Comment: well how to find users profile id?

Comment: Check the answer, updated it.

Comment: Some enterprising fb users have created entities specifically for use in such macros, e.g. `[[roxsign]]`, `[[midfing]]`.

Comment: Also it looks like you no longer need to find out the numeric user ID—the name-like alias seems to work now.

Comment: It seems doesn't work now. I tried it several times but failed.

Answer (score 12):

> smile :-) :) :] =)
>
> frown :-( :( :[ =(
>
> tongue :-P :P :-p :p =P
>
> grin :-D :D =D
>
> gasp :-O :O :-o :o
>
> wink ;-) ;)
>
> glasses 8-) 8) B-) B)
>
> sunglasses 8-| 8| B-| B|
>
> grumpy >:( >:-(
>
> unsure :/ :-/ :\ :-\
>
> cry :'(
>
> devil 3:) 3:-)
>
> angel O:) O:-)
>
> kiss :-* :*
>
> heart <3
>
> kiki ^_^
>
> squint -_-
>
> confused o.O O.o
>
> upset >:O >:-O >:o >:-o
>
> pacman :v
>
> curly lips :3
>
> robot :|]
>
> Chris Putnam :putnam:
>
> Shark (^^^)
>
> Penguin <(")
>
> 42 :42:
>
> "Like" thumbs-up  (y)
>
> friendly turd  :poop:

**Sources:**

- http://calebbrown.id.au/blog/2008/04/complete-list-facebook-chat-emoticons
- http://www.facebookchatemoticons.com/
- http://www.techlila.com/use-chat-smileys-emoticons-facebook-chat/

Comment: There are a bunch more (including many of the `[[...]]` variety) here: http://emoticon.wikia.com/wiki/Facebook_Chat_Emoticons